# "Keychain System cannot be found"

Tags: wifi, macos, keychain

After upgrading to 10.11.2 my laptop stopped connecting automatically to my WiFi network. When I manually select the network it connects, but then it pops up a dialog saying "Keychain System cannot be found to store {SSID}".

When I look at the Keychain Access app I see a System keychain, and it is located at `/Library/Keychains/System.keychain`. But there is also a directory `/System/Library/Keychains/`. Will moving the `System.keychain` file under `/Library/Keychains/` to `/System/Library/Keychains/` fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What solved the issue for me was using `First Aid` on the *Macintosh HD* from the *Disk Utility* app:

1. Start *Disk Utility*
2. Make sure to select *Macintosh HD* and not the top level storage (which represents the physical disk). You want to fix the *logical* partition.
3. Click the *First Aid* button at the top of the window.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in the correct place - don't move it.

It sounds like your `System.keychain` is corrupted. Can you see the entries in it in Keychain Access app?

I'd suggest you create a new Keychain in the Keychain Access app and then try copying the entries over (you can just drag and drop them). You may find most can be recovered and you can replace the corrupted Keychain with your new one.

Comment: I can see the entries for the System keychain in the Keychain Access app, and when I manually connect to wifi the OS can use the correct entry in the keychain to authenticate with the network. So I don't think corruption is the problem. For some reason one part of the OS can't find the keychain, and another can. I recently upgraded from 10.10, so that's why I suspect something's broken because of a path issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this some sort of a permission thingie here after the upgrade? Could you please reboot into recovery mode and try "Repair permissions"?

Comment: Is there an error message I can look for in the logs that would suggest that this is actually a permissions error? I'd like to have a diagnosis before I try any particular fix.

Comment: You could start the Console App and watch the logfiles during opening the keychain...

Comment: The only thing I see that stands out is a bunch of messages like this: "kernel[0]: Sandbox: coreduetd(68815) deny(1) file-read-metadata /" for several different paths when I reconnect to the wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Keychain First Aid` submenu from `Keychain Access` and try to select `Verify` option and then hit `Start`. If any error is detected, try `Repair` option.

Comment: I cannot find this on 10.11.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's removed, but in OS X 10.11.2. Look at: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219949/117407

Comment: I actually have 10.11.2 installed.

Comment: This "feature" doesn't exist anymore (I believe it's 10.11.2 and up).

Answer (score 0):

For people coming from google, this might be obvious, but make sure the keychain 'System' actually exists:
Open up Keychain access, and if 'System' isn't under 'Keychains' on the left, then add it by right clicking on that area and choosing 'New Keychain...' That fixed the issue for me.

(This was on Mac OS Sierra)