# Not able to store Wi-Fi network passwords in keychain

Tags: network, wifi, password, keychain

A few years back I gave my laptop in to fix a charging problem, and though that was resolved pretty easily, when I got it back I seemed to be having problems with logging on to Wi-Fi. What happens is, the Wi-Fi network that was already saved before the reparation does not connect automatically, I have to click on the Wi-Fi icon and choose the network to connect, and it will connect, but it will say `a keychain could not be found to store -network`. So that's ok, but the really annoying thing is that with any new network I have to manually select it and then type in the password every time, and it will connect but still give me the same message.

I am using a mid 2012 MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

Answer (score 1):

[Keychain First Aid](https://www.passfab.com/mac/everything-you-want-to-know-about-keychain-first-aid.html) may solve your problem. It [has been removed in later Mac OS versions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219926/where-has-keychain-first-aid-gone) (starting with 10.11 El Capitan), but it should still be available for 10.10 Yosemite.

1. Launch the Keychain Access app, located in `Applications` > `Utilities`
2. From the Keychain app, go to the `Keychain Access` menu in the top-left and then select `Keychain First Aid`. [image: keychain first aid]
3. From the Keychain First Aid window, select `Repair` and click `Start` [image: Keychain First Aid window options]

Comment: No, this did not work :( But thank you for the suggestion!